# Change mail's font

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, fonts, html-email

I created a procedure to send mails which globally corresponds to the HTML Emails procedure from this [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql#html) except the plain/text part with the `p_text_msg` variable.

I create HTML messages with other procedures. I would like to know if there is a way to modify the font of my messages in PL_SQL.

For now, I simply add a `<style>` part in the CSS of the HTML message:

```
body { font-family : Verdana; font-size : 8pt;}
```

A little detail, I use **Oracle 9i**.

Comment: How are you constructing the HTML body of the message? Wouldn't you just embed a stylesheet the same as you would for any other HTML document?

Comment: Initially, I didn't need to change the text size. So, for now, I add a <style> tag on some procedures creating HTML mails. But I would like to find a way to change it in PL_SQL, because I don't want to manually change the futures HTML mails...

Comment: It would help to see the PL/SQL code that you currently have.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson There is a link in my post that is 80% similar.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to display a specific font in HTML email is to inline it in every `<p>` tag.

**Instead of this:**

```
<style>
    body {font-family:Verdana;}
</style>
<body>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</body>
```

**Something like this:**

```
<body>
    <p style="font-family:Verdana;">Some text</p>
    <p style="font-family:Verdana;">Some more text</p>
</body>
```

Annoying, I know! If there's a way to do that with PL_SQL, that should solve your issue in almost every email client.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. However, I'm looking for a way to do it in PL_SQL because I don't want to manually modify each procedures creating html messages.

Comment: Aye, unfortunately I can't help much there but wanted to contribute at least something.

Comment: I appreciated your contribution, don't worry for that :)